COBOL program calling LE C program
I am trying to call a LE C program (test program that just prints the arguments) from my COBOL program.
I pass a structure to my C program and print the received values. However, as you can see in the output, the first 2 bytes of function are missing when printing argv[1]. Could anyone help fix this?
Is this the correct way to call a LE C program from COBOL program (I need to pass upto 3 structures like CALL cpgm USING struct1 struct2 struct3) or is there a better way? Any examples would really help.
COBOL program:
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                    
PROGRAM-ID. COBPGM.                         
DATA DIVISION.                              
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                    
01  EXPARM.                                 
    05  FUNKTION       PIC X(4) VALUE SPACES
    05  FUNC REDEFINES FUNKTION.            
        10 FILLER      PIC X(03).           
        10 FUNC-SUFFIX PIC X.               
    05  STAT           PIC X(2) VALUE SPACES
    05  ID-CODE   PIC S9(4) COMP.      
    05  ID-NAME   PIC X(08).           
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                         
    MOVE 'FUNC' TO FUNKTION.                
    MOVE '1' TO FUNC-SUFFIX.                
    MOVE 'OK' TO STAT.                      
    MOVE 1234 TO ID-CODE.              
    MOVE 'IDNAME ' TO ID-NAME.        
                                                
    CALL 'CPGM' USING EXPARM.               
    STOP RUN.

C program:
#include <stdio.h>                 
#include <stdlib.h>                
#include <string.h>                
#include <errno.h>                 
#include <limits.h>                
typedef struct EXPARM1{            
char FUNCTION[4];                  
char STATUS[3];                    
int ID_CODE;                  
char ID_NAME[9];              
}EXPARM;                           
                               
int main(int argc, char **argv) {  
printf("argc : %d\n",argc);        
if (argc>=1) {                     
    printf("argv[0] : %s\n",argv[0]);
    printf("argv[1] : %s\n",argv[1]);
}                                  
return 0;                          
}

Output:
argc : 2
argv.0. : COBPGM
argv.1. : N1OK.KIDNAME ENDMBLK-.s..
the above '.K' in the output is 1234 in HEX and not sure where ENDMBLK is coming from.
Tried to run the program and it printed the above output which I can't make sense of.

In the C program, the EXPARM typedef is irrelevant as it isn't used.  Please read about how to create an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example
— or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example
— the same idea by a different name).  You've not done a bad job of minimization — the C code is pretty close to minimal.

You need to study the COBOL manual to understand what it does in the CALL 'CPGM' USING EXPARM. statement — especially what it does with the USING argument when it is what C would call a structure (would it be a record in COBOL?).    You might find some useful information by printing a hex dump of the data in argv[1] — it would tell you what the bytes are.

I think the fields FILLER and FUNC-SUFFIX overwrite/overlay the FUNC element.  If so, the second MOVE overwrites/damages the result of the first.  I'd suggest dropping the second MOVE from the COBOL code and seeing whether that makes things any different/clearer.

Note that if you're on a Unix-like system, the program is probably executed via the execve()
function call, and that expects each argument to the executed program to be a null-terminated string.  I suspect that the EXPARM structure doesn't have a null byte anywhere in it, and the ENDMBLK… characters happened to be next in memory and were included in the argument until it did run across a null byte.  The COBOL manual probably indicates how you need to set up the arguments to the program executed.

It looks like the calling convention expects a VARCHAR type string with the an "S9(4) COMP" containing the length as the first element of the structure. Also add an S9(4) COMP set to zero at the end of the structure to prevent C string handling going crazy.
